# How do I create data source in eclipse level in atg .?

Tags: eclipse, jdbc, atg

How do I create data source in eclipse level in atg .?

1. I have removed jdbc folder from config and configured that jdbc folder in eclipse.
2. On build of Eclipse, that data source file needs to point the database and needs to start the server.

Like dynamo/ admin / or project need to up.

Can anyone help me with how to do these?

Comment: Firstly, please elaborate on your context. e.g. have you created a new module using the Eclipse ATG plugin, or are you using an existing module? What is the base ATG setup? Did you use CIM? Is it Commerce Reference Store? Also, please explain which version of ATG you are using, and particularly on what application server? Secondly, please tell us what you are trying to achieve. Do you want to connect connection to the database directly from within ATG, or do you want to make use of data sources configured in the app server? Thirdly, are you starting your ATG instance from within Eclipse

Comment: 1. weblogic server am using.